# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf: How to get the value of an object of a list after an iteration

Tags: java, html, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hi all and thank you for reading my issue.

I'm programming an application using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf, and I have the following problem.

I'm iterating a list of objects, and displaying a button under them using, and my goal is to update the database getting the value of one attribute from a specific iterated object, but the attribute retrieved is empty, and it'd should not be empty.

My controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mostrar_usuarios")
public class MostrarUsuariosController {

    private final UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    public MostrarUsuariosController(UsuarioService usuarioService) {
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mostrarVista(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
        UsuarioVO u = (UsuarioVO) session.getAttribute("usuarioActivo");
        if (u != null) {
            ArrayList<UsuarioVO> listaUsuarios = (ArrayList<UsuarioVO>) this.usuarioService.retrieveAll();
            model.addAttribute("usuarios", listaUsuarios);
            return "mostrar_usuarios";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/paginaprincipal";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registrarse(@ModelAttribute("usuario") UsuarioVO usuario, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
        UsuarioVO u = (UsuarioVO) session.getAttribute("usuarioActivo");
        if (u != null) {
            u.getSeguidos().add(usuario); // usuario comes empty
            this.usuarioService.update(u);
            return "mostrar_usuarios";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/paginaprincipal";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my html + thymeleaf code:

```
        <div class="media-container-row" th:each="usuario: ${usuarios}">
            <div class="title col-12 col-md-8">
                <br></br>
                <hr />
                <br></br>
                <h5 class="align-center pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-2"
                    th:text="${usuario.nombre + ' @' + usuario.arroba}"
                    id="tamanioTexto"></h5>
                <form class="align-center pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-2" action="#" method="POST" th:object="${usuario}" id="tamanioPie">
                <button id="boton" type="submit">Seguir</button>
                </form>
                <br></br>
                <hr />
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

All works fine, except the `th:object="${usuario}" #style it as code`, with what I want to get the specific iterated object, depending on the button clicked within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

> As per Thymeleaf official documentation : Values for **th:object** attributes in form tags must be variable
>   expressions (${...}) specifying only the **name of a model attribute**,
>   without property navigation

th:each="usuario: ${usuarios} and th:object="${usuario}", both are same.

Here you are using it as a local reference. Try renaming the th:each var name or replacing with command object/ model attribute name.

Comment: I got it, but I think it does not solve my problem, because what I want to do is make the object a model attribute, depending of which button of the list is clicked. I hope to have explained better.